# Can we use a class created in an .asp file in a C# file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic

In my company one of the applications is a classic asp based application.In this application one the .asp has a Class Definition and a function associated with the class.I want to use this class an aspx.cs page.Is it possible to do this and how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not mix. You will have to refactor the class into an appropriate C# class library or file.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just copy the class over to a .CS file since ASP and ASP.NET don't live in the same space. You've already got the code, just move it and modify it as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible, AFAIK.

The code in your .asp file is interpreted at runtime.  Your .aspx file is precompiled.  Odds are that your .asp file is VBScript which is a completely different language.